# Passing FILE pointer to a function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm little bit confused over here, not quite sure about this. What I'm trying to do is to pass the name of a file through `terminal`/`cmd` that will be opened and read from.

```
myfunction(char* fileName, FILE* readFile)
{
    if((readFile = fopen(fileName,"r")) == NULL)
    {
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }
    return FILE_NO_ERROR;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE* openReadFile;
    if(myfunction(argv[1], openReadFile) != FILE_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\n %s : ERROR opening file. \n", __FUNCTION__);
    }
}
```

My question is if i pass a pointer `openReadFile` to `myfunction()` will a `readFile` pointer to opened file be saved into `openReadFile` pointer or do i need to put `*readFile` when opening.

Comment: You need to pass `&openReadFile` into the function if you want the updated pointer passed back to the caller.  The parameter declaration of the function would be `FILE** readFile`

Comment: ... or pass the successful pointer back as function value, or `NULL`.

Comment: Can't i just dereference readFile when fopen-ing?

Comment: If you want to read from the file in `main()` you can't, because it's pointer value is lost after the function returns.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Ummm... myfunction() does not return anything.....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

FILE * needs to be a pointer, so in main openReadFile stays as a pointer.
myfunction takes **, so we can update the FILE * with the result from fopen
    `*readFile = fopen...` updates the pointer.

```
int myfunction(char* fileName, FILE** readFile) /* pointer pointer to allow pointer to be changed */
{
    if(( *readFile = fopen(fileName,"r")) == NULL)
    {
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }
    return FILE_NO_ERROR;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* openReadFile; /* This needs to be a pointer. */
    if(myfunction(argv[1], &openReadFile) != FILE_NO_ERROR) /* allow address to be updated */
    {
        printf("\n %s : ERROR opening file. \n", __FUNCTION__);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think i got it, if i would have only one `*` in `int myfunction(char* fileName, FILE** readFile)` i would be basicly changing on what readFile is pointing, and with double `*` im changing on which pointer from main is pointing too. Yay.