# Why I have to Passing FILE pointer to potiner to a function

Tags: c

I trying to make a function it need passing a pointer of FILE object.
And read the data from the file and output the result into another file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fileOperation(FILE *file, char *mode, char *filename){
    char fileAddress[50] = "\0";
    sprintf(fileAddress,"%s%s","../",filename);
    file = fopen(fileAddress,mode);
    if(mode == "rt"){
        if(file == NULL){
            printf("\nError when opening input file, program exiting\n");
            printf("\nType a number & press the enter key to finish");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else if(mode == "wt"){
        if(file == NULL){
            printf("\nError when creating input file, program exiting\n");
            printf("\nType a number & press the enter key to finish");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void averageTemp(FILE *infile, FILE *outfile){
    int count = 0;
    float readNumber, sum = 0, average = 0;
    
    printf("Program reading data from file and calculate the average temperature");
    while (fscanf(infile,"%f",&readNumber)!=EOF)
    {
        printf(".");
        sum += readNumber;
        count ++;
    }
    average = sum/count;
    fprintf(outfile, "The average is %4.3f\n", average);
}

int main (void){
    FILE *finput, *fresult;

    printf("Program is reading temperature data from a file\n");

    fileOperation(finput,"rt","my_dat.dat");
    fileOperation(fresult,"wt","result.dat");

    averageTemp(finput,fresult);
}
```

The programme will stuck while it process the function averageTemp and crash after few seconds later.
And I follow the answer in another question in StackOverflow.
[Passing FILE pointer to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378000/passing-file-pointer-to-a-functio) .
And modify my code to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fileOperation(FILE **file, char *mode, char *filename){
    char fileAddress[50] = "\0";
    sprintf(fileAddress,"%s%s","../Lab sheet 9/",filename);
    *file = fopen(fileAddress,mode);
    if(mode == "rt"){
        if(*file == NULL){
            printf("\nError when opening input file, program exiting\n");
            printf("\nType a number & press the enter key to finish");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else if(mode == "wt"){
        if(*file == NULL){
            printf("\nError when creating input file, program exiting\n");
            printf("\nType a number & press the enter key to finish");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void averageTemp(FILE **infile, FILE **outfile){
    int count = 0;
    float readNumber, sum = 0, average = 0;
    
    printf("Program reading data from file and calculate the average temperature");
    while (fscanf(*infile,"%f",&readNumber)!=EOF)
    {
        printf(".");
        sum += readNumber;
        count ++;
    }
    average = sum/count;
    fprintf(*outfile, "The average is %4.3f\n", average);
}

int main (void){
    FILE *finput, *fresult;

    printf("Program is reading temperature data from a file\n");

    fileOperation(&finput,"rt","my_dat.dat");
    fileOperation(&fresult,"wt","result.dat");

    averageTemp(&finput,&fresult);
}
```

Now the code and running properly. Howerver the question I juse mentioned above didn't explain why I have to passing FILE pointer to potiner instead of a FILE pointer. Can anyone explain the reason? Thanks

Comment: Pretend that instead of `FILE*` it was `int`. What would the program `void f(int x) {x=5;} int main() {int j = 7; f(j); printf("%d\n", j);}` do? Would it work properly?

Comment: If you pass `finput` to a function, that function cannot change the value of `finput` in the caller.  If you pass `&finput`, the function can modify it.